# Android: Как найти View по ID в цикле?

Tags: android, java

Имеется 30 `ImageButton` c ID от 1 до 30.
Пытаюсь найти по ID в цикле. По идее должно быть что-то вроде:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++){ 
    ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.i));
    }
```

Естественно, такой код не работает =) 
Как мне по очереди найти каждую `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разочарую Вас, но в скомпилированном коде уже нет имен, а только номера. Поэтому в такой постановке задача нерешаемая.

Правильный способ решения.

Создать массив id,

```
int[] img = new int[]{R.id.img1, R.id.img2, R.id.imgX};

// и дальше в коде
for (int i = 0; i < img.length(); i++) {
  ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(img[i]);
  imgbtn.work();
}
```

Но если так слишком просто, то можно хитрее

```
ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup)activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
int count = decor.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View view = decor.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
       ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)view;
       imgbtn.work();
     }
}
```

Но здесь проблема в том, что их нужно будет идентифицировать (например по Tag или Caption) и никто не гарантирует порядка.

Comment: Как нерешаема?
    
    int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "id", this.getPackageName());

API Level 1: [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)  

[How to get a resource id with a known ressource name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name)  

Другое дело - тормоза, это да...

Answer (score 0):

Имя переменной не может начинаться с цифры, и без цикла ошибку выдавать будет, если очень хочешь провести инициализацию через цикл можешь посмотреть напрямую значение в R.id (выглядит примерно так `0x7f070008`) но очень не стабильный вариант, пересоберешь проект  и не факт что  будет работать, намного надежнее руками ))

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++){ 
    ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(getResId("imgbtn" + i, "id", this));
}

publiс int getResId(String ResName, String className, Context ctx) {
    try {
        return ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(ResName, className, ctx.getPackageName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так - при создании элементов присваивать им тэг и id и обрабатывать их сначала по тэгу потом по id

для начала надо указать лайоут

я делаю так

```
  mainL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_elements);
```

потом добавляем теги и id к элементам. 
Кстати - я не заметил что установленный id меняется.
все остается на своих местах

```
newSpinner.setId(id);
newSpinner.setTag(""+type[0]);
```

потом в кнопку, по нажатию которой все это обрабатывается

```
  public void btn_checkall(View v){

    final int childCount = mainL.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          View element = mainL.getChildAt(i);

        //если это EditText
        if (element instanceof EditText) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)element;
            System.out.println("ELEMENTS EditText getId=>"+editText.getId()+ " getTag=>"+element.getTag()+
            " getText=>"+editText.getText());
        }

        //если это CheckBox
        if (element instanceof CheckBox) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)element;
            System.out.println("ELEMENTS CheckBox getId=>"+checkBox.getId()+ " getTag=>"+checkBox.getTag()+
            " getText=>"+checkBox.getText());
        }

    }
}
```

логи

```
  ELEMENTS EditText getId=>1523 getTag=>single-line getText=>vtvgbghy
```

Answer (score -2):

1. ты не можешь знать какие ИД у батонна, потому что генерятся автоматически
2. придется всетаки биндить кнопки ручками
3. какойто перегруженый интерфейс кнопками

Comment: Когда создавал кнопки, присваивал им ID с помощью setId. Неужели это не работает?